# XPATH to get multiple values

Tags: xpath

```
<values>
<value index="1">
<token>
<secret>
<client_key>
</value>
<value index="2">
<token>
<secret>
<client_key>
</value>
<value index="3">
<token>
<secret>
<client_key>
</value>
</values>
```

Can anyone please help me with the xpath to get the token value from all the indexes . The no of indexes will vary each time and not a constant.possible values are (1 or >1)

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed and so cannot be queried via XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Searches for `tokens` inside `values` that has attribute `index`

```
 //value[@index]/token
```